# substring with linq?

Tags: c#, linq, string

I've got collection of words, and i wanna create collection  from this collection limited to 5 chars

Input:

```
Car
Collection
Limited
stackoverflow
```

Output:

```
car
colle
limit
stack
```

word.Substring(0,5) throws exception (length)

word.Take(10) is not good idea, too...

Any good ideas ??

Comment: You get the exception because car is only 3 characters long and you are asking for a SubString of 5 characters.

Comment: yes, I know. Situation is much more complicated, and this which I 've described to you has a biggest problem which this complicated situation :)

Comment: As cool as LINQ is (and I really think it's cool), how is using it for this better/more readable than an "old fashioned" foreach loop?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

LINQ to objects for this scenario?  You can do a select as in this:

```
from w in words
select new
{
  Word = (w.Length > 5) ? w.Substring(0, 5) : w
};
```

Essentially, ?: gets you around this issue.

Comment: You should add a check for `null` elements. That is, `var subwords = words.Where(w => w != null).Select(w => w.Length > 5 ? w.Substring(0, 5) : w);`.

Answer (score 10):

```
var words = new [] { "Car", "Collection", "Limited", "stackoverflow" };
IEnumerable<string> cropped = words.Select(word => 
                                    word[0..Math.Min(5, word.Length)]);
```

Ranges are available in C# 8, otherwise you'll need to do:

```
IEnumerable<string> cropped = words.Select(word => 
                                    word.Substring(0, Math.Min(5, word.Length)));
```

Answer (score 2):

Something you can do, is

```
string partialText = text.Substring(0, Math.Min(text.Length, 5));
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the kind of answer you were looking for would look like this:

```
var x = new string[] {"car", "Collection", "Limited", "stackoverflow" };
var output = x.Select(word => String.Join("", word.Take(5).ToList()));
```

The variable "output" contains the result:

```
car 
Colle 
Limit
stack
```

and the string "car" doesn't throw an exception.

But while Join and Take(5) works, it's generally much simpler to use, as was suggested in another answer,

```
subString = word.Substring(0,Math.Min(5,word.Length));
```

The latter code is more human-readable and lightweight, though there is definitely a slight coolness factor to using Linq on a string to take the first five characters, without having to check the length of the string.